# how to solve the recurrence T(n)=T(n-1)+T(n-3)-T(n-4), n>=4

Tags: recurrence

How to solve the recurrence equation

1.T(n)=T(n-1)+T(n-3)-T(n-4), n>=4

2.subject to T(n)=n for 0<=n<=3

Comment: What language is that?

Comment: First of all: This is not the site to post your homeworks onto. Always show your attempts/ideas or any general thoughts. Secondly: I think your question rather belongs to http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From calculating the first numbers you can quickly suspect that the solution is `T(n) = n`.

You can then prove this using **mathematical induction**:

**Basis:**

For the first element, `n = 4`, we can calculate the value like:

```
T(4) = T(3) + T(1) - T(0) = 3 + 1 - 0 = 4
```

so the statement is true.

**Inductive step:**

Assuming `T(n) = n`, show that `T(n+1) = n+1`:

```
T(n+1) = T(n) + T(n-2) - T(n-3) = n + (n-2) - (n-3) = n+1
```

which shows `T(n) = n` for all `n >= 0`.

Answer (score 0):

I created algorithm in language similar to C style. I guess C# would run it if you add function Main and required includes.

```
int CountT(int n)
{
    if (n < 0)
    {
        throw new Exception("N is lower than zero");
    }
    else if (n <= 3)
    {
        return n;
    }
    else
    {
        return CountT(n-1)+CountT(n-3)-CountT(n-4);
    }
}
```